# Haproxy resolvers configuration

Tags: http, nginx, haproxy

I have a service exposed with Nginx, I'm testing it with:

```
curl something.mydomain.com --resolve something.mydomain.com:80:<IP-ADDRESS>
```

This works exactly as expected, now I'm trying to expose this with HAproxy using resolvers:

```
acl host_something hdr(host) -i something.mydomain.com

use_backend some_backend if host_something

resolvers some_resolver
    nameserver something.mydomain.com <IP-ADDRESS>:80

backend some_backend
    server server1 something.mydomain.com:80 check resolvers some_resolver
```

This is the result so far:

```
some_backend/<NOSRV> 0/-1/-1/-1/0 503 2021 - - SC-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {|} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

What am I missing / doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The haproxy resolvers section requires an DNS server [Server IP address resolution using DNS](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#5.3) what's different to the curl [--resolve](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) option which expects an IP.

You can add the ip to the /etc/hosts file so that haproxy can resolve it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)